# Is 'have reached' grammatical in 'If you have reached this level by the end of the month, I will buy you a car'?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

If you **have** reached this level by the end of the month, I will buy you a car.

Is this tense correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because it's a real  conditional. In this type of conditional, we use the present tense in the *if-clause*. The present perfect *have reached* is a present tense. You could also just use the simple present *reach*.

One thing we don't do in English is use future will in the if-clause here. We would not say the following:

*If you will  reach this level by the end of the month, I will buy you a car.

The asterisk (*) indicates this is not grammatical in standard English.